# Why does MongoRepository save return an empty json and save empty value when a variable is not empty?

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a simple document:

```
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class ProductUnit {
    @Id
    String id;
    private String name;
    private Integer price;
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
}
```

Simple `MongoRepository` :

```
public interface productRepo extends MongoRepository<ProductUnit,String> {
    ProductUnit deleteByName(String name);
    List<ProductUnit> findByPrice(Integer price);
}
```

and `Service` :

```
@Service
public class productServiseImpl implements productServise {

    @Autowired
    productRepo repository;

    @Override
    public ProductUnit saveOrUpdate(ProductUnit productUnit) {
        System.out.println("inside save or update");
        return repository.save(productUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductUnit> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public ProductUnit deleteUnitByPrice(String name) {
        return repository.deleteByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductUnit> findByPrice(Integer price) {
        return repository.findByPrice(price);
    }
}
```

Now , inside `RestController` , I pass **id** through a post request and use a random class to generate a random value of the price and name .At this stage everything is fine, i.e. all values were initialized correctly, but when it comes to `service.saveOrUpdate(forSave)` It stores the value incorrectly, i.e. the request returns an empty json and the `findAll` method returns a list of empty **json**.Can you tell me what the error is? thanks

```
@RestController

public class productUnitRestController {

    @Autowired
    productServise service;
    @Autowired
    Supplier<MetaInfGenerator> generatorSupplier;

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public List<ProductUnit> getAllProoduct(){
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/products")
    public ProductUnit createProoduct(@RequestParam("id") Optional<String> newId){
        System.out.println("***** iside PostMapping ******");
        MetaInfGenerator generator = generatorSupplier.get();
        System.out.println("***** supplier PostMapping ******");
        ProductUnit forSave = ProductUnit.builder()
                                    .id(newId.get())
                                    .name(generator.getRandomString())
                                    .price(generator.getRandomInteger())
                                    .localDateTime(LocalDateTime.now()).build();
        System.out.println(forSave);
        return service.saveOrUpdate(forSave);

    }
}
```

Comment: does 'list of empty json' look like this? `[{}]`?
does it work if you add getter/setter to ProductUnit?

Comment: @indybee yes like this

Comment: can try adding getter/setter to ProductUnit?

Comment: @indybee haha, I think I've already figured out how to write a simple rest Service correctly, but I'll forget to add something. Thank you so much for watching and responding !